# How to use Confidence Score in % for each individual prediction in ML.net

Tags: machine-learning, ml.net

In the below code, I come down to those 4 lines of code where I `Train the model`, Then `make predictions` on that model. Then it is possible to show the `metrics.Accuracy score in %` in the MessageBox.

```
var model = pipeline.Fit(trainData); // Train the model
var predictions = model.Transform(testData); // Make predictions
var metrics = context.BinaryClassification.EvaluateNonCalibrated(predictions, labelColumnName: "Label");
MessageBox.Show(metrics.Accuracy.ToString());
```

That `Accuracy score` is for the testData altogether.
My question and what I am looking for is how it would be possible to get a Confidence Score in % for each prediction individually in that testData, if that particular datapoint belongs to the positive class (1).
 
From what I have understand, it would be needed to `Calibrate` the `rawScores` in combination with the `trueLabels`. But this is what I don't know how to do, or if there is any inbuilt function in ML.net?

Is there any method in ML.net where this is possible or how can we do this?

At the end of the code we have this information, if that is useful in this sense:

```
Vector<float> rawScores = MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Single.DenseVector.OfArray(predictions.GetColumn<float>("Score").ToArray());
Vector<float> trueLabels = MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Single.DenseVector.OfArray(predictions.GetColumn<float>("Label").ToArray());
```

All code is below:

```
        public class Inputs
        {
            [LoadColumn(0)] public double feature1;
            [LoadColumn(1)] public double feature2;
            [LoadColumn(2)] public bool Label;
        }
        void _function(IDataView calibrationData)
        {
            var context = new MLContext(seed: 0);

            // Load data into a list of Input objects
            var dataList = new List<Inputs>();
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                double feature1 = random.NextDouble();
                double feature2 = random.NextDouble();
                bool label = random.Next(2) == 1; // Generate random true (1) or false (0) for the label
                dataList.Add(new Inputs { feature1 = feature1, feature2 = feature2, Label = label });
            }

            // Load the data from the list
            var data = context.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(dataList);

            var trainTestData = context.Data.TrainTestSplit(data, testFraction: 0.2, seed: 0);
            var trainData = trainTestData.TrainSet;
            var testData = trainTestData.TestSet;

            // Define the data preprocessing pipeline. Concatenate which features to use!
            var pipeline = context.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "feature1", "feature2")
                .Append(context.Transforms.Conversion.ConvertType("Features", "Features", DataKind.Single))
                .Append(context.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax("Features"))
                .Append(context.BinaryClassification.Trainers.FastTree());

            var model = pipeline.Fit(trainData); // Train the model
            var predictions = model.Transform(testData); // Make predictions
            var metrics = context.BinaryClassification.EvaluateNonCalibrated(predictions, labelColumnName: "Label");
            MessageBox.Show(metrics.Accuracy.ToString());

            // Calibration data (raw scores and true labels)
            List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
            Vector<float> rawScores = MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Single.DenseVector.OfArray(predictions.GetColumn<float>("Score").ToArray());
            Vector<float> trueLabels = MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Single.DenseVector.OfArray(predictions.GetColumn<float>("Label").ToArray());
        }
```

I have created all code that Train and Test the model. But from here I simply do not know how to achieve Confidence Scores in %.